# Is there a way to throttle or limit resources used by a user in Oracle?

Tags: performance, oracle, oracle10g, report, throttling

I have a multi-user web application  and am encountering issues when a third party reporting application queries my Oracle 10g database.

The reporting queries are slowing the system and impacting all other users.

Is there a way to throttle this user's session so their queries don't impact the other users?

Comment: You can limit the number of concurrent user sessions a user may have.  Limiting the number of concurrent logons this third party app has would require the third parties to respect your operational limits.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [Database Resource Manager](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/mgmt_db.htm#i41580) to manage workload. Have a look at the [Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dbrm001.htm#sthref2340) or at [this example from Joel Kallman's APEX blog](http://joelkallman.blogspot.com/2009/08/oracle-database-resource-manager-and.html).

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you can only throttle sessions based on CPU in 10g, which usually isn't the problem with long running queries. The most useful thing would be limits placed on disk I/O, which it appears is now available in 11g in the [Database Resource Manager](http://www.filibeto.org/sun/lib/nonsun/oracle/11.1.0.6.0/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dbrm004.htm#CHDDCGGG).

Comment: I see how you can switch to a different consumer group based on IO in 11g, but I don't see a way to limit the I/O of the consumer group as you can with CPU.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Leigh, it looks like you're correct, but at least you can detect the high I/O process and switch to a lower priority group, or even kill it if so desired. It would be something to experiment with to see how effective it would be. My answer was more directed at the OP's question regarding 10g.